# Macro not showing up before VBE is open

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I've added a VBA module to an Excel workbook and saved the project as an XLSM file. One of the subroutines was defined such that it shows on the Macro list (the one opened by Alt+F8).

When I open the XLSM file, the Macro list is empty. But if I open the VBE (Alt+F11) even for a moment, the macro shows up in the Macro list.

What should I do so the Macro is there without opening VBE? Did I miss some step in somehow "publishing" the macro?

#### Edit

[Here](https://github.com/tontonsb/notes/raw/master/dv2.xlsm) is the workbook itself. Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open the workbook. Enable editing and macros.
2. Press Alt+F8, observe that the list is empty.
3. Press Alt+F11 and hide or close the VBE.
4. Press Alt+F8, observe that there is now a macro in the list.

Sorry, I can't observe the problem without enabling macros. Don't enable macros on workbooks found on the internet if you don't know what you are doing!

Comment: If you have used the keyword **Private** in the sub declaration or,, if your macro have a PARAMETER or if U have written code as a FUNCTION rather than a SUBROUTINE !!    If so, the sub won’t appear in the ALT + F8 macro selector !!

Comment: It's not private, it has no parameters, it is a `Sub`. And it shows on the selector, but only after visual basic editor has been opened at least once. Which is the problem.

Comment: If possible the please share the WB with us & let me check !!

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the post to include it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. After downloading the WB, opening it and enabling editing and content, `alt-F8` opens the macro dialog with `PrepareFilesForPasvaldibas()` showing.

Comment: @Džuris ,,, the problem doesn't exists since after used Alt+F8 ,,, got the Macro `PrepareFilesForPasvaldibas` appearing on dialogue box, and as soon I've altered other Macros from PRIVATE to PUBLIC ,,, they are also appearing  !!

Comment: @RajeshS I'm glad it doesn't appear on all machines, but it's real for me, including if I download the file from the location that I shared. Might be something with settings but I don't remember customizing my excel installation that much. What you see is what I would like to see — list containing that one macro. The others are hidden intentionally.